# Lapply function to data frame returned last values only

Tags: r, lapply

Got a dataframe with numbers spelled in english:

```
  df.en <- data.frame(var1 = c("two thousand","one hundred", "seventyfour"),
                 var2 = c("twenty two","fifty", "six"), stringsAsFactors = F)


> df.en
          var1       var2
1 two thousand twenty two
2  one hundred      fifty
3  seventyfour        six
```

And a quick & dirty user defined function to guess if is possible to translate to numbers. (below)

When applying function to some elements to test, worked ok:

```
> translateToNumbers("eighteen")
[1] 18
> translateToNumbers("one hundred and twenty two")
[1] 122
```

The issue is when using lapply to get the above dataframe translated:

```
> lapply(df.en, translateToNumbers)
```

Just the last evaluated values are returned

```
$var1
[1] 74

$var2
[1] 6
```

We need all dataframe translated if possible. Here below the function:

```
library(magrittr)

    translateToNumbers <- function(x) {
          x[] <- gsub("^thousand", "1000)+", x , ignore.case = T) %>%
          sub("eleven", "+11", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("twelve", "+12", . , ignore.case = T ) %>%
          gsub("thirteen", "+13", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("fourteen", "+14", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("fifteen", "+15", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("sixteen", "+16", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("seventeen", "+17", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("eighteen", "+18", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("nineteen", "+19", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("twenty", "+20", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("thirty", "+30", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("forty", "+40", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("fifty", "+50", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("sixty", "+60", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("seventy", "+70", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("eighty", "+80", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("ninety", "+90", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("one hundred", "+100", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("two hundred", "+200", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("three hundred", "+300", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("four hundred", "+400", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("five hundred", "+500", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("six hundred", "+600", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("seven hundred", "+700", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("eight hundred", "+800", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("nine hundred", "+900", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("one", "+1", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("two", "+2", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("three", "+3", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("four", "+4", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("five", "+5", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("six", "+6", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("seven", "+7", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("eight", "+8", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("nine", "+9", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("millions", ")*(1000000)+(0", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("million", ")*(1000000)+(0", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("thousand", ")*(1000)+(0", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("ten", "+10", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("and", "", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub(" ", "", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("^", "(0", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("$", ")", . , ignore.case = T) %>%
          gsub("\\(0\\(", "", . , ignore.case = T ) %>%
          gsub("\\+\\+", "\\+\\(", . , ignore.case = T ) %>%
          gsub("\\)\\+\\)", "\\)", . , ignore.case = T )
     return(eval(parse( text = x)))
    }
```

Comment: Are you going to use `apply` (as in your title) or `lapply`, as in your post? They work differently. If `lapply`. why do you feed it the entire data.frame? Shouldn't you do `df_en[['var1]]`?

Comment: Eventually the function `to_number()` cannot handle vectors. Try `lapply(df.en, Vectorize(to_number))` What is the difference between the functions `translateToNumbers` and `to_number`?

Comment: My bad. A typo.

Comment: But lapply is supposed to work on every element from a vector as documentation states. So why "vectorize"

Comment: @Forge data.frame is not a vector, you can think of it as a list of vectors. In jogo's code, you vectorize the function and then lapply it to each column of the data.frame.